# FireStore Error in Cursor - cursor position is outside the range

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a method to return some data from FireStore, which is used for pagination in my Flutter app.

```
  static Future<QuerySnapshot> getAllItems({int count: 12, dynamic lastKey}) {

    if (lastKey != null) {
      return Firestore.instance
          .collection('uploads')
          .where('active', isEqualTo: true)
          .where('purge', isEqualTo: false)
          .startAfter([lastKey])
          .orderBy("active_time", descending: true)
          .where('active_time', isLessThanOrEqualTo: DateTime.now())
          .limit(count)
          .getDocuments();
    } else {
      return Firestore.instance
          .collection('uploads')
          .where('active', isEqualTo: true)
          .where('purge', isEqualTo: false)
          .orderBy("active_time", descending: true)
          .where('active_time', isLessThanOrEqualTo: DateTime.now())
          .limit(count)
          .getDocuments();
    }
  }
```

When lastKey value is not passed, all works fine. But when I pass the string value of lastKey, I get the below error.

```
cursor position is outside the range of the original query
```

The field `active_time` is a TimeStamp type in FireStore. Index is created for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me document the issue I faced.

The issue was due to the difference of data type. The Firebase database and my dart variable type was different.. ie.. DateTime and Timestamp. After fixing this, the code started to work.

Answer (score 0):

Since `active_time` is a DateTime, `lastKey` should also be a DateTime.

From the Docs on `startAfter`

> Takes a list of values, creates and returns a new Query that starts
>   after the provided fields relative to the order of the query.

https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/startAfter.html

Comment: It is already of the same data type as mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: @Purus I would suggest not making it a dynamic then

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by that

Comment: getAllItems takes an argument called lastKey which is of type dynamic. It should be of type DateTime.